# Как вести GIT проекта на Python+Django?

Tags: python, django, git, python-2.x

Имеется мини проект на python(2.7) + django (1.11). Для удобства установлен virtualenv.

Весь проект имеет структуру:

```
project\
    \gui
        \gui
        \project_app
        \static
        \templates
        manage.py
    \Include
    \Lib
    \libs
    \Scripts
    pyenv.cfg
```

Как в данном случае будет правильно вести разработку через GIT, чтобы потом максимально просто разворачивать это всё на сервере? С учетом того, что изменены и некоторые стандартные приложения django (по пути Lib\site-packages) (не класть же всю папку в git). Docker на сервере использовать запрещено.

Comment: Что значит `изменены и некоторые стандартные приложения django`? Вы изменяли файлы в пакетах установленных в virtualenv?

Comment: @roman-konoval да, изменял приложение auth

Comment: Это очень ненормальная практика. Нужно решить задачу, для которой вы меняли файлы в virtualenv нормальным способом. Вы не можете включать virtualenv в исходный код (и систему контроля версий), т.к. virtualenv - системно-зависимый, его работа на другой системе не гарантируется. Его всегда нужно устанавливать заново.

Answer (score 0):

я при разработке на Django, поступаю таким образом:

1. Создаю проект
2. Создаю приложение
3. Перехожу в директрорию приложения
4. В консоли поочерёдно: git init, git add ., git commit -m 'Ваш коммит', git push origin master(в случае если используется удалённый репозиторий)

А вообще хорошее руководство по git: https://githowto.com/ru

Comment: p.s. Теперь ветка **master** на **GitHub** переименована в **main**. Теперь для пуша используется команда: `git push origin main` [источник](https://github.com/github/renaming)

Comment: @Sherlock в самом git ветку никто не переименовывал, так что это неактуально

Comment: @andreymal Так я специально и написал, что **GitHub** переименовали ветку.

Comment: @Sherlock так я специально и написал, что **в самом git** ветку никто не переименовывал, и ваша команда git push origin main просто не сработает, потому что никакой ветки main не существует